# Selenium Java - Click if element exists, continue with the next command if element not found

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

i'm trying to create a script to test a web site (js application), code is almost done but i encounter a problem. The script its supposed to edit a question on the website (the question uses a lot of variables from a database) and depending on were the script failed or if anyone else edited the question there is a chance for the script to get a pop-up message(not a separate window or new tab). I want the code to:

Click the element if present or go to the next line of code if the element does not exist.

I tried using but it does not help:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[2]")).click();                                        
// Click unselect all
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Romania")).click();                                     
// Select Romania
log.debug("Select Romania");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Germany")).click();                                     
// Select Germany
log.debug("Select Germany");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/a")).click();                                     
// Click Save Button
log.debug("Click Save");
Thread.sleep(3000);

**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/button")).click();**                
// Pop-up message
log.debug("Click Pop-up message");
Thread.sleep(3000);

/////////////// Single Answer

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Change")).click();                                      
// Click Change Template
log.debug("Click Change");
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

The you can find the line with the issue between **** (pop-up), how can i click if the element exists or move to driver.findElement(By.linkText("Change")).click(); if element not found.

Please let me know if more info is required.

Edit:
To give more details about why the pop-up appears. The script edits a question, the questions have multiple templates and the script is supposed to go through each template after selecting the template the script will associate a variable from the database to the question.
Templates:

Single answer question
Single answer dropdown question
Multiple answer question
Multiple answer dropdown question
Date

The pop-up message appears as a warning (that the variable used will be removed )when the template is changed from multiple answer to single answer/date or the other way around.
In the perfect case if the script finishes successfully (it will end with single answer dropdown - first question is single answer so the pop-up does not appear )and no one edits the question i will not encounter the pop-up but if the script fails due to x reason after changing the template to multiple answer, when i restart the script i will receive that pop-up/warning.

The issue also occurs when changing the language of the question as shown in the code above, i have multiple steps were i encounter this problem.

At the moment in order for the script to run and avoid the problem mentioned above, i need to edit the question myself and select a specific language and template before running the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no matching elements are found, an instance of `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

```
try {
    WebElement popUp = driver.findElement(By./**your expression**/);
    popUp.click();  
} catch(NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException e) {
    log.debug("Impossible to click the pop-up. Reason: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I tried the above command i had the following result:

- If the element does not exist the script continues (this is what i wanted)

- If the element exists, an exception is thrown after clicking the button:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a class="font-size-sm" onclick="$('#id4a').hide();
$('#id49').hide();
$('#id49').fadeIn();">...</a> is not clickable at point (770, 881). Other element would receive the click: <div id="id9a" class="modal in" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)

Comment: Maybe you access a wrong element? Check it out with a `.isClickable()` call.

Comment: The problem was not the element, i needed to add a wait after the try(as there is a delay after clicking the button). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend two approaches.

1. Simply poll the DOM for the pop-up and click the button if exists:

   ```
   List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[4]//button"));
   if (!button.isEmpty()) {
       button.get(0).click();
   }
   ....
   ```

`driver.findElements()` is used to avoid try-catching `NoSuchElementException` in case using `driver.findElement()`

2. You may use explicit wait to wait some time for the button to appear:

   ```
   try{List<WebElement> button = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementsLocated(By.xpath("//div[4]//button")));
       if (!button.isEmpty()) {
          button.get(0).click();
       }
   }
   catch(TimeoutException e)
   {
   }
   ```

Comment: There is no need for a wait, there are to options: 1. The button appears or 2. The button does not appear

Comment: OP may want to use wait since the page may be edited & changed by other users